# IE8 is ignoring accesskeys on links/input boxes and instead brings up browser menus

Tags: jquery, key, shortcut, alt

I am working on a fairly complex intranet site, which is using a lot of jQuery.
We decided to add "accesskey" short cuts to certain elements (only to link elements and text input fields).

The problem I am experiencing only happens in IE8 (or ChromeFrame with IE8).
Chrome appears to work fine.

We are using accesskeys that are used by IE8 natively (eg: ALT-C is already assigned to bring up Favorites in IE8 but we are using the accesskey="C"

```
eg)

<a class="client" accesskey="c">Client</a>
```

All link events are typically added post-render using jQuery:

```
    $("a.client").click(function(){ ... });
```

For some reason, Internet Explorer 8 (which I have read is supposed to give priority to the page when it comes to using the accesskeys, is totally ignoring that rule, and stealing the event.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you try and recreate your issue in a simplistic example using jsfiddle?

Comment: I did do a simple example using the accesskeys, and the simple example works perfectly in IE8.  My guess is that there is something in the reams of jQuery code and plugins we are using that is capturing the event, and then propogating it up the stack, bypassing the browsers mechanism for trapping the alt-key combos.

Comment: yeah - a real edge case - hard to diagnose without seeing/debugging